# How to return the control of execution from the method of one class to the main method of a different class?

Tags: java

This class is called in the class MAIN_PROGRAM to execute the method 'menu1' accordingly. If user takes 3 as input, the control of execution should be returned to the main_menu method of class MAIN_PROGRAM.

I tried to use System.exit(0) in case 3 as I thought it would close only the program estimation_of_order_of_magnitude and not the whole process but it did not work. In other words, if case 3 is executed, main_menu must execute.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.*;
public class estimation_of_order_of_magnitude
{

    void menu1()
    {
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter");
        int n=scr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter 1 to calculate height of object");
        System.out.println("enter 2 to calculate length of object");
        System.out.println("enter 3 to return to main menu");   // to return to mainmenu of other class
        System.out.println("enter your chice");
        while(true)
        {
        switch(n)   
        {
        case 1:height_of_object();
        case 2:length_of_object();
        case 3:System.exit(0);
        }
        }
    }
}

import java.util.*;

class MAIN_PROGRAM

{
void main_menu()

    {   
estimation_of_order_of_magnitude obj=new estimation_of_order_of_magnitude();

    encoding_and_decoding object=new encoding_and_decoding();
    Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter");
    int n1=scr.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter 1 for estimation of order of magnitude");
    System.out.println("enter 2 for encoding and decoding");
    System.out.println("enter 3 to exit");
    System.out.println("enter your choice");
 while(true)

         { switch(n1)
            {
            case 1:obj.menu();
            case 2:object();
            case 3:System.exit(0);
            }

          } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.exit(0);
```

This exits the entire program. To return from a function to the method that called it, use

```
return;
```